# Условные переменные - где ошибка?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Опять у меня вопрос из-за чужого вопроса - на этот раз [вот этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/923997/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-c).

Я захотел попробовать свои силы в параллельном программировании, и решить задачу (один поток добавляет в лист строки, другой их оттуда берет, сортирует и записывает в свой поток) через условные переменные. Оно вроде работает, но исредка затыкается на

```
......
<-- String consumed
<-- Wait string produced
--> String produced
--> Wait string consumed
```

и стоит. Где я дурак? Если я пытаюсь добавить условие к условной переменной, получается только хуже.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

constexpr int ELEMENTS = 10;

void printList(const list<string>& l) {
    cout <<"LIST:\n";
    for(const auto& s: l) cout << s << " ";
    cout << endl;
    }

string new_string() {
    string s;
    for(int i = rand()%8+1; i > 0; --i)
        s += rand()%26+'a';
    return s;
    }

// Сигналы о том, что строка готова и что обработана
condition_variable strReady, strHandled;
mutex mReady, mHandled;

void createList(list<string>& l) {
        {
        unique_lock lck(mHandled); // Ждем запуска второго потока
        strHandled.wait(lck);      // Без проверок, так как заведомо знаем,
        }                              // что он один

    for(int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; ++i) {
        // Начинает создавать
        string s = new_string();
        l.push_back(s);

        cout << "--> String produced" << endl;

        strReady.notify_one();     // Уведомляем о готовности строки

        cout << "--> Wait string consumed" << endl;

        unique_lock lck(mHandled); // и ждем разрешения работать
        strHandled.wait(lck);      // Без проверок, так как заведомо знаем,
        }                              // что поток обработчика единственный
    }

void handleList(list<string>& l1, list<string>& l2) {

    strHandled.notify_one();       // Сообщаем о запуске, можно работать

    for(int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; ++i) {
        string s;
        // Ждет сигнала
            {
            unique_lock lck(mReady);
            strReady.wait(lck);    // Без проверок, так как заведомо знаем,
            // что поток создателя единственный

            s = l1.back();
            cout << "<-- String consumed" << endl;
            }

        strHandled.notify_one();   // Строка скопирована, сообщаем, что
        // можно работать дальше
        sort(s.begin(),s.end());
        l2.push_back(s);
        cout << "<-- Wait string produced" << endl;
        }
    }

int main() {
    srand(time(0));

    list<string> l1, l2;
    thread t1(createList,ref(l1));
    thread t2(handleList,ref(l1),ref(l2));
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    printList(l1);
    printList(l2);

    }
```

Еще непонятка - есть `srand(time(0))`, но строки всегда одни и те же.

Comment: Подскажу со `srand` - ее нужно в каждом потоке вызывать свою. По крайней мере в VC++ она привязана к потоку - использует thread-local память (кажется, это так называется).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас несколько проблем с кодом, разной степени проблемности.
Первое, какие-то бесполезные прологи:

```
{
    unique_lock lck(mHandled); // Ждем запуска второго потока
    strHandled.wait(lck);      // Без проверок, так как заведомо знаем,
}
```

И `strHandled.notify_one();` — убрать. Эти прологи не нужны.
Второе:

> Без проверок, так как заведомо знаем, что поток обработчика
>   единственный

Проверки нужны, т.к. существует spurious wakeup. Т.е. поток можно проснуться не потому, что получил сигнал, а просто потому что. Так что дополнительные проверки нужны **всегда**.

Третье, у Вас в коде гонка, а значит UB. В первом потоке Вы делаете `l.push_back(s);` без защиты мьютекса, что создаёт гонку с вот этой строкой из второго потока: `s = l1.back();`. Закрывайте добавление строки в список мьютексом `mReady` и уходит.

А вообще, т.к. Вы пытаетесь полностью сериализовать 2 потока, т.е. сделать их последовательно выполнимыми, Вам достаточно одного мьюеткса — не нужно тут два, ресурс-то один.

Четвёртое, и самое главное: если `strReady.notify_one();` выполняется и тут же идёт переключение на другой поток, т.е. `wait` не успевает отработать, тогда весь код второго потока может успеть отработать, включая `strHandled.notify_one();`, что приведёт к тому, что сигнал улетит во вселенную и первый поток никогда не узнает о том, что он был. Расставьте правильно мьютексы, чтобы исключить эту ситуацию, тогда зависания должны прекратиться.

Но чтобы код стал корректным, нужно применить все замечания.

---

Минимально изменив изначальный код, можно получить что-то такое:

```
condition_variable strReady, strHandled;
mutex mGuard;

void createList(list<string>& l) {
    for(int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; ++i) {
        string s = new_string();
        unique_lock lck(mGuard);
        l.push_back(s);
        cout << "--> String produced" << endl;
        strReady.notify_one(); 
        cout << "--> Wait string consumed" << endl;
        strHandled.wait(lck);      
    } 
}

void handleList(list<string>& l1, list<string>& l2) {

    size_t processed{0};
    for(int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; ++i) {
        string s;
        {
            unique_lock lck(mGuard);
            strReady.wait(lck, [&](){ return processed < l1.size(); });
            s = l1.back();
            ++processed;
            cout << "<-- String consumed" << endl;
        }
        strHandled.notify_one();  
        sort(s.begin(), s.end());
        l2.push_back(s);
        cout << "<-- Wait string produced" << endl;
    }
}
```

Из очевидных минусов: нет уведомления потока производителя, что потребитель действительно потребил. Из-за этого приходится держать мьютекс и для вывода, и для уведомления, а также нет защиты от «перепроизводства» из-за spurious wakeup, но идея должна быть ясна.

Comment: Я более-менее понял первые три пункта...а не могли бы вы немного подробнее объяснить четвертый? У меня прологт были как раз чтоб не "улетело во вселенную" сообщение, но  если пролог не нужен - то  как это стыкуетсяя с улетом? И как правильно расставить мьютексы - что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Mikhailo, добавил код.

Answer (score 0):

Есть у меня подозрения, что все же нужно добавлять условия к условным переменным во избежание ложных срабатываний даже при единственном потоке. Добавим флаг готовности переменной в списке:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

constexpr int ELEMENTS = 20;

void printList(const list<string>& l) {
    cout <<"LIST:\n";
    for(const auto& s: l) cout << s << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

string new_string() {
    string s;
    for(int i = rand()%8+1; i > 0; --i)
        s += rand()%26+'a';
    return s;
}

condition_variable strReady, strHandled;
mutex mReady, mHandled;
bool isReady = false;

void createList(list<string>& l) {

    srand(time(0));

    for(int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; ++i) {
        string s = new_string();
        l.push_back(s);

        cout << "--> String produced\n";

        isReady = true;
        strReady.notify_all(); 

        cout << "--> Wait string consumed\n";

        unique_lock lck(mHandled); 
        strHandled.wait(lck,[]() {return !isReady;}); 
    }
}

void handleList(list<string>& l1, list<string>& l2) {

    for(int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; ++i) {
        string s;
        {
            unique_lock lck(mReady);
            strReady.wait(lck,[]() {return isReady;});

            s = l1.back();
            cout << "<-- String consumed\n";
        }

        isReady = false;
        strHandled.notify_all(); 

        sort(s.begin(),s.end());
        l2.push_back(s);
        cout << "<-- Wait string produced\n";
    }
}

int main() {

    list<string> l1, l2;
    thread t1(createList,ref(l1));
    thread t2(handleList,ref(l1),ref(l2));
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    printList(l1);
    printList(l2);

}
```

Comment: Запустил в батнике. на 93 выполнении заткнулось.

Comment: У себя прогнал 20000 раз. "Затыков" не было. VC++ 2017. Конечно, это не гарантия, что все верно - на то и параллельные программы... Извините, так сказать, *Feci quod potui faciant meliora potentes*...